# Grails Test Case summary Report

Tags: grails

while running the test-app command , i only get the below Test Case summary report if i REMOVE the `xalan-2.4.0` from Lib directory in grails project.

Tests with failure and errors
Package summary
Show all tests

Can anyone suggest me what will be the reason behind that ?